# Magento1 to Magento2 data migration ignore orders, invoice, shipping, creditmemo

Tags: magento2, migration

I want to migrate all data without orders, invoice, shipping, creditmemo.
How can i ignore it in config file? Is it possible?

Comment: are you using migration tool form Magento ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Magento data migration tool then you can comment order from config file.
If you are using other tool like Uber data migration tool then they have separate step for order migration.
Kindly let me know if you need more info.